# Fiber-preserving diffeomorphism

Tags: vector-spaces, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, diffeomorphism

What does it mean in the definition 7.1(ii) that the diffeomorphism
$$\phi_U$$ is **fiber-preserving**?
In what sense/how technically it preserves fibers?
They have never defined this in the book before.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The textbook is referring the property of $\phi_U$ restricting to a linear isomorphism between $E_p$ and $p \times \mathbb{R}^r$ as fiber-preserving. The reason behind this terminology is that if we restrict $M$ to $p$, then the following [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THRAZ.png) commutes where $pr_1$ is the projection onto the first component of $p \times \mathbb{R}^r$. This is essentially saying that $E$ resembles the base space $M$ when zooming in close enough on $p$.